# Min function in Raster Calculator of Arcgis 10 doesn't work

Tags: gis, geospatial, arcgis

I know that `min` function in raster calculator of ArcGIS 10 doesn't work but I don't know that which function can I use to solve my problem.

I had this in ArcGIS 9.3  at raster calculator.

```
rule6 = min([population], [gasStation],[Industrial],[falt])
```

How can I do this in ArcGIS 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is different ways including :
Implementing a Cell Statistics tool in ArcGIS Or
writing a code in python